# XCode6 storyboard, TableViewController can't see navigation Items

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode6

I was migrating some code over form XCode5 to XCode6 and I realized I couldn't figure out how to see my Navigation Items as part of my TableViewController on the storyboard.  As you can see in the following image i have an AddPilot button

[image]

My Storyboard however looks like this and there is no visual representation of the Add Pilot of which I can drag off to create segues etc. 
[image]

Do i have to do something on the display to get it to show?

Answer (score 0):

In my case complete reinstall of xcode didn't help, so I clicked on "Show the assistant editor" and than preview my storyboard.

[image]

It helped in some magical way.